# VBA not finding the excel file even when file is present in the folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am opening the excel file in VBA using

```
Set Workbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(File)
```

Where

```
File = "C:\GSTR Automation\GSTR2\February\1000\ReverseCharge\Outputs\ReverseChargeZonic_1000.xlsx"
```

I am getting the vba error that it could'nt find the file.

Comment: Can you open this file manually? Did you try to restart PC?

Comment: Hello , Yes I did both the things

Comment: Can you attach the full code with variable File?

Comment: Yes I have a long code in which I am opening multiple files and it was all working from last 3 months and suddenly today I started getting this error.

Comment: And can you make a screenshot of the error? That we could help you.

Comment: How to attach the screenshot here?

Comment: MsgBox Dir(File) giving me null value in the message box

Comment: `MsgBox Dir(File)` If this is empty then the file actually doesnt exist. Right click on the file and click on properties. Copy the path and filename from there and then use that

Comment: But file is present there , I have verified the path manually

Comment: I have copied the file location and name from the file still getting the same error

Comment: Can you write to the folder ***C:\GSTR Automation\GSTR2\February\1000\ReverseCharge\Outputs\*** from VBA? To test this, create a text file from VBA and save it to that folder..

Comment: Or try what I mentioned in the answer below

Comment: Can you change C drive in your path to D or etc. Save file to other drive or flash card. Then run macros again. If it is ok, the problem is in the access to drive C. Your Windows is installed on drive C?

Comment: this is the most unusual behavior of VBA till now  I just copied the file path from properties section of the file and then it worked . But the file path earlier was exactly the same. I still dont get what was the issue

Comment: Zoom the screen and look closely at the digits 0 and 1 in case they are letters O or l. Also look for double spaces where there should only be one.

Answer (score 2):

> But file is present there , I have verified the path manually – karan arora 33 mins ago

> I have copied the file location and name from the file still getting the same error – karan arora 30 mins ago

This is not an answer but may help you identify where could be the problem in such a scenario.

**Logic:**

This code (not fully tested) will take a path and folder by folder will check if it exists. I created the same structure in my `C:` so that you can see how it works

[image]

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim Ar As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim DoesFileExist As Boolean
    
    sFile = "C:\GSTR Automation\GSTR2\February\1000\ReverseCharge\Outputs\ReverseChargeZonic_1000.xlsx"
    
    Ar = Split(sFile, "\")
    
    If UBound(Ar) = 1 Then
        MsgBox "File Exists: " & FileFolderExists(sFile)
    Else
        sFile = Ar(0)
        
        For i = 1 To UBound(Ar)
            sFile = sFile & "\" & Ar(i)
            
            DoesFileExist = FileFolderExists(sFile)
            
            If DoesFileExist = False Then
                MsgBox sFile & " not found"
                Exit Sub
            Else
                MsgBox sFile & " found"
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if file/folder exists
Private Function FileFolderExists(strFullPath As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True
Whoa:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

**In Action:**

[image]

Now I changed `February` to `January` in the above path

[image]

Now see how the above code responds

[image]